# Complex Numbers prove $z^n+\bar z^n$ is a real number

Tags: complex-analysis

My text book asks us to prove $z^n+\bar z^n$ is a real number where $\bar z$ is $z$ conjigate. $z$ is a nonzero complex number and $n$ is an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$z^n+\bar{z}^n=z^n+\overline{z^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Write $z=re^{i\theta}$.